# Migrating from Standalone Apache SOLR to SOLR Cloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We have a standalone Apache Solr setup in local Server for testing purpose,  with around 10 cores created in it. Now we are planning to setup a new Solrcloud environment in AWS with numShards:3 and replicationFact:3 .

Is there any way to transfer existing Apache Solr core (Schema and data) to new SolrCloud environment in AWS.

Comment: By far the easiest thing to do is to reindex your current data source to the new Solr cluster. Any reason why that won't work? Reindexing is an important feature to support for most Solr installations, since changes to the schema often will require reindexing content.

Comment: I am newbie in Solr Cloud, can you please explain more.                                                      1) How to take backup of Solar Core data from local server ?. and                                              
2)  How to re-index using it in SolrCloud Collection in AWS?

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't (if you can avoid it) use the data already in Solr, but instead reindex it from the original source - where the data originates from. Instead of indexing it into your local Solr instance, index it into the new SolrCloud cluster. If you _have_ to use the data already in Solr, the easiest way is if all your fields are stored - you can use the DataImportHandler with the SolrEntityProcessor to index content from an existing Solr installation (if reachable from your DataImportHandler node).

Comment: Thanks for your help. What i actually need is, we have developers currently working on Local standalone Solr server. Now we are planning to move SolrCloud setup in AWS Infrastructure. We don't need data in Solr to be migrated to SolrCloud. What we need to do is transfer only core (Content in core.properties and conf folder)  not data (data folder) to Collection in SolrCloud. Please help –

Comment: In that case; try [Using Zookeeper to Manage Configuration Files](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/using-zookeeper-to-manage-configuration-files.html#UsingZooKeepertoManageConfigurationFiles-UploadingConfigurationFilesusingbin_solrorSolrJ) first, then ask the relevant question where you're having trouble implementing it.

Comment: Thanks .Uploaded Configuration file to Zookeeper.                                    
  bin/solr zk upconfig -n <name for configset> -d <path to directory with configset>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used ZooKeeper to Manage Configuration Files. Uploaded Configuration file to Zookeeper : /bin/solr zk upconfig -n  -d